# The groupoid $C^*$ algebra associated to a certain groupoid

Tags: c-star-algebras, groupoids

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be  the set of all natural numbers. We define  a  groupoid  structure on $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ as  follows:

We put $G^1=\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}},\;G^0 =\{(a_n)\in G^1\mid a_{2n-1}=a_{2n},\;\forall n \in \mathbb{n}\}$. We define the range and  source maps $r,s:G^1 \to G^0$ as follows:$$r((a_n))=(a_1, a_1, a_3,a_3,a_5,a_5\ldots,a_{2n+1}, a_{2n+1}\ldots)\\s((a_n))=(a_2, a_2,a_4,a_4, a_6, a_6,\ldots,a_{2n}, a_{2n}\ldots)$$

To  define the  composition map of the groupoid, we assume that $r((b_n))=s((c_n))$.   Put $b=(b_n),\;c=(c_n)$. The  composition is $$c\circ b=(c_1,b_2,c_3,b_4,\ldots,c_{2n-1},b_{2n},\ldots)$$

The groupoid is equipped with the  discrete topology and we consider the associated  groupoid $C^* $  algebra.

> What is  a  precise description of this $C^*$ algebra?Is it identical to a well known $C^*$ algebra? What is its $K$-theory?

Comment: What are the identities?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  I guess that you mean "what is the inverse?" Yes? In this case the inverse of  a  sequence is given by swiching even and odd index, right? There are various definition of groupoid and I think we  are following two different (but actually the same) definitions.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  I am not  considering the (small) category  definition but I am considering the other one. Am I  missing some thing?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  I still wonder  what do you mean by identity. In this example, as usual, r is the  right identity and  s is  the left identity. right?

Comment: If this is a groupoid it must have a map $i:G^0\to G^1$, assigning to an object of the groupoid its identity morphism. I asked what is this map in your case.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  The  inclusion. But  a  groupoid  has no a universal identity. I am following the  definition of  groupoid  according to  definition in the  book of  Alain Connes  Non  Commutative  geometry.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Please  see item 3  of  definition 1 page 104. I think in the  example of this post  r and  s  play the role of  left and  right identity    http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf

Comment: Oh I see thanks. Identity map is the embedding of the subset $G^0$ into $G^1$. So your groupoid is isomorphic to $G^0\times G^0$, with $r$ and $s$ the first and the second projection, and $G^0\hookrightarrow G^0\times G^0$ the diagonal, right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Yes. Thank you. so  your comment  helped me to understand that the  groupoid in the question is  not  a  new  structure, it is  isomorphic to the groupoid  associated to the equivalent relation on $\mathbb{N}$ collapsing all points to one point. Yes? and its  resulting C* algebra is the inductive limit of  Matrix algebras, yes?

Comment: Yes, except not on $\mathbb N$ but on ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}$.